# Добавление записи в бд c# через модель данных

Tags: c#, база-данных

У меня есть метод для добавления рандомной записи в бд:

```
private void AlphaClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectBaseEntities projectBaseEntities = new ProjectBaseEntities();
        Logins logins = new Logins();
        Users users = new Users();
        users.id = 0;
        users.Firstname = "Null";
        users.Secondname = "Null";
        logins.login = "Login";
        logins.password = "Password";
        logins.id = 0;
        logins.Role = 0;
        //logins.Users = users;
        projectBaseEntities.Users.Add(users);
        projectBaseEntities.Logins.Add(logins);
        projectBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Однако при вызове в саму бд ничего не добавляется, как я понял. Есть ли возможность через модель данных добавлять запись уже в саму бд?

Comment: `как я понял` как вы это поняли?

Comment: После `SaveChanges` вызовите `projectBaseEntities.Users.Count()` и выведите это значение куда-нибудь. Увеличивается количество записей?

Comment: Проблема в том, что созданный мною объект хранит созданные записи в себе. Как мне этот объект передать в саму базу?

Comment: Метод `SaveChanges` сохранит объекты в БД. / Хотя, давайте уточним: что такое `ProjectBaseEntities` - это класс унаследованный от `DbContext`?

Comment: да. я просто думаю что при создании нового объекта вязь с бд не установлена

Comment: Я перечитал, что  SaveChanges сохраняет данные в бд. Но при попытке проверить возвращаемое число я получил 0. В чем может быть проблема?